# xml to json auto script

Tags: php, json, xml

I have a couple of xml feeds which I need to convert to json. My service provider uploads the xml files 2-3 times a day to our server. At this point I use codebeautify.org to convert the files to json and then re-load them back to our server. Is there a way that I could have this conversion done automatically for me either by way of a php script or similar. Appreciate advice on how I should tackle it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your current effort so we can troubleshoot. SO is not a codewriting service.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
function removeNamespaceFromXML( $xml )
{
    // Because I know all of the the namespaces that will possibly appear in 
    // in the XML string I can just hard code them and check for 
    // them to remove them
    $toRemove = ['rap', 'turss', 'crim', 'cred', 'j', 'rap-code', 'evic'];
    // This is part of a regex I will use to remove the namespace declaration from string
    $nameSpaceDefRegEx = '(\S+)=["\']?((?:.(?!["\']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"\']))+.)["\']?';

    // Cycle through each namespace and remove it from the XML string
   foreach( $toRemove as $remove ) {
        // First remove the namespace from the opening of the tag
        $xml = str_replace('<' . $remove . ':', '<', $xml);
        // Now remove the namespace from the closing of the tag
        $xml = str_replace('</' . $remove . ':', '</', $xml);
        // This XML uses the name space with CommentText, so remove that too
        $xml = str_replace($remove . ':commentText', 'commentText', $xml);
        // Complete the pattern for RegEx to remove this namespace declaration
        $pattern = "/xmlns:{$remove}{$nameSpaceDefRegEx}/";
        // Remove the actual namespace declaration using the Pattern
        $xml = preg_replace($pattern, '', $xml, 1);
    }

    // Return sanitized and cleaned up XML with no namespaces
    return $xml;
}

function namespacedXMLToArray($xml)
{
    // One function to both clean the XML string and return an array
    return json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string(removeNamespaceFromXML($xml))), true);
}

print_r(namespacedXMLToArray($xml));
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/converting-xml-to-jsonarray

Comment: Can someone tell me why -1 ?